# How can I reduce the amount of "whitespace" above my h2 (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I've got a piece of a page that looks like this:

[image]

It's coming along, but I want less "dead space" or whitespace between the top border and the "Top 10 Items Purchased" h2 element.

This is the pertinent CSS and HTML:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contents {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.topleft {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sectiontext {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
  color: green;
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="topleft">
          <h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>
          <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2">
            </input>
            <label>to</label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2">
            </input>
          </div>

          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Item Code</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>100250</td>
              <td>Artichokes Green Globe 18 Size</td>
              <td>9084</td>
            </tr>
```

I tried adding:

```
padding-top: -12px;
```

...to the sectiontext class, and then the topleft class, and that was not effective.

What must I do to reduce the space between the top border and first line of text (h2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

`.sectiontext {
  margin-top:-4px;
}`

Not really the best solution, but it should be a quick fix for your issue.
Adjust `-4px` to whatever.

Comment: Thanks, @SankarRaj, I fixed it.

Comment: This is opposite of what I needed, but led me to that conclusion: namely, that I needed to add "margin-top: -4px;" to the sectiontext class.

Comment: This answer is the closest to correct, so if you change it to margin-top: -4px" I will accept it.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the check! @B.ClayShannon

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the top-margin from your h2. You can add `margin-top:0` to `.section-text` and then adjust accordingly.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contents {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.topleft {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0px 16px 16px 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sectiontext {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
  color: green;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="contents container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="topleft">
          <h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>
          <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2" />

            <label>to</label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2" />

          </div>

          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Item Code</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>100250</td>
              <td>Artichokes Green Globe 18 Size</td>
              <td>9084</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contents {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.topleft {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sectiontext {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
  color: green;
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="topleft">
          <h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>
          <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2">
            </input>
            <label>to</label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2">
            </input>
          </div>

          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Item Code</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>100250</td>
              <td>Artichokes Green Globe 18 Size</td>
              <td>9084</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Rather than reducing the whitespace between the border and the h2, that removes the whitespace between the border and the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have `margin-top: 16px;` set on the `topleft` class. That that element will have a margin-top of 16px. So there for the children in that class are 16px below what you might be expecting.

In your CSS removing `margin-top: 16px;` from your `topleft` class should work. Of course you can just adjust `16px` to be something lower if you still want a little bit of a top margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing margins from h2.

H2 comes with following:-

```
 h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Try this:-

```
  h2{
        margin:0
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In .topLeft set padding: 0px 16px;

Comment: That does reduce the space between the border and the h2, but it also reduces the total height of that div (the entire bordered area), which I don't want.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon In that case you can also either set padding-bottom:32px; to the table or set a fixed height on div.topLeft. I would recommend the former

Answer (score 1):

Is that you want?

Removed top padding from `.topleft` class.

Also the `row` should be wrapped into the `container` class.

One more thing, **Unlike margin, padding values cannot be negative.** <del>`padding-top: -12px;`</del>

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contents {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.topleft {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0px 16px 16px 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sectiontext {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
  color: green;
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="contents container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="topleft">
          <h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>
          <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2" />

            <label>to</label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2" />

          </div>

          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Item Code</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>100250</td>
              <td>Artichokes Green Globe 18 Size</td>
              <td>9084</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That completely broke it (removing the top padding from the topleft class and adding "container" to the class list in the outermost div); it made the bottom two quadrants on the page disappear altogether and made the top two 9X uglier than a bag of butts.

I did have a custom "container" class, but even when I removed it, the same thing resulted. This is it:

.containerHideForNow {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Answer (score 0):

Remove top margin, for example:

.sectiontext {

margin-top:0px;

}